# Confirm method works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, dom-events

I am using confirm method of JavaScript, which executes fine in Chrome, but it is not working in Firefox. `addListItem()` function is not executed when I am using Firefox. (check=true) I did validation of radio buttons group. jf all buttons are checked then only want to submit form.

```
  if(check) {   
      confirmOnsubmit();
  } else {
      alert('Please make sure all statememt are answered and remark is filled if rating of any statement given as Rarely or Never');
            return false;
  }


   function confirmOnsubmit(){
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to submit")) {
         addListItem();
         return true;       
      } else {
         alert("You selected cancel");
         return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of the method addListItem()?

Comment: addListItem(). sets the values of the form to sharepoint list. Its work fine in chrome and IE but in Firefox it does not execute

Comment: Which one do you use,jsom or rest api?

Comment: I have used som

Comment: some js file may not load,you could use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addListItem,"sp.js"); to excute method until the js file load.sp.js you could change to other file you used .Some js file may need you load manully.

Comment: if(!check) {   
     alert('Please make sure all statememt are answered and remark is filled if rating of any statement given as Rarely or Never');
            return false;
  } else {
      confirmOnsubmit();
  }


   function confirmOnsubmit(){
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to submit")) {
         addListItem();
         return true;       
      } else {
         alert("You selected cancel");
         return false;
      }
    }

Comment: The above code worked for me. as i call a function confirmonsubmit in else instead of if loop. it works fine in chrome, IE and firefox also.